# Prevent manipulation cookie on client side

Tags: php, security, cookies

I know that cookie only work with string and does not accept array... so far so good

Creating and reading a cookie:

```
setcookie( 'name' , 'my name is foo' );
echo $_COOKIE['name']; // output my name is foo
```

If the user change the cookie name to: `name[]`
he changes the cookie `name` in an array and we get an error: **Array to string conversion.**

1) how can we prevent this kind of safe handling of cookies? 
2) if we work with a class of cookie, the get method should return only strings?

Comment: Why not use [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) instead?

Comment: There's nothing you can do to prevent the client from changing cookies.

Comment: if I work with a class for cookies as some frameworks, I only return string, since cookies not accept array?

Comment: You cannot prevent manipulation of cookies at client side, but you can always validate it at server side for what you expect, even though it is not fully fail proof.

Comment: @Jake King, not use session because I want to use cookie

Comment: Cookies can accept arrays. PHP puts each array element in a separate cookie with names like `name[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Use session variables instead of cookies.
2. Validate your cookes when you use them. One part of this could be encrypting the cookie value, and prepending a private key before the value. The script can decrypt the cookie and test whether it begins with the private key. You can also test whether the user renamed the cookie to an array:

   ```
   if (is_string($_COOKIE['name'])) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: kohana uses salt and the cookie name